# in a scroll view i need to set image height as activity height of the device

Tags: java, android, android-activity

i need to set image height as activity height of the device programatically
So i need to retrieve activity size of the device, this size varies from device to device

i tried this

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

but this gives the entire size(including navigationbar and everthing) of the phone screen but i need the activity size

Comment: set imageview's height as matchparent in your layout?

Comment: its scroll view

Comment: Put your scrollview under viewGroup and set image in that viewgroup

Answer (score 0):

If you want visible activity height excluding toolbar. Calculate tool/action bar height and set your image view layout_height as 
required height = activity height-toolbar height

Comment: its scroll view

Answer (score 0):

use a method like this:

```
public static Point getAppUsableScreenSize(Context context) {
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size;
}
```

to get the usable screen size

Comment: it returns the same size as what displayMetrics.heightPixels; returns, its total size i need the activity height excluding action bar status bar

Comment: it returns the size without status bar and navigation bars, but it does include the toolbar